# Bitcoind JSON-RPC : Java Jersey Client : Unexpected end of file from server Error

Tags: json, jersey, bitcoin, json-rpc, bitcoind

I am very new to bitcoin and this is my first experiment with bitcoind.

We have been trying to develop an Java based application on BTC using bitcoind (using testnet). We are using simple HTTP Post using Jersey client with basic authentication like given below. We already have jersey client as part of project dependencies. We are running on Mac OS. The bitcoind and java client are hosted in the same system.

```
Client client = Client.create();

String url = "http://"+username+':'+password+"@localhost:18333";
//String url = "http://localhost:18333";
System.out.println("URL is : "+url);
WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);

Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
   return new PasswordAuthentication (username, password.toCharArray());
    }
    });

String input = "{\"method\":\"getblockcount\",\"params\":[],\"id\":\"1\"}";
ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class, input);
```

When we execute this, we are getting

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
   at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:772)
   at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:633)
   at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:769)
```

From the exception what I understand is, there are some server side errors but i am not able to see errors in the log files. The degug.log does not give any details.

The entries in the bitcoin.conf file is as follows:

```
rpcuser=bitcoinrpc
rpcpassword=5UKQTzWTf7EEJnkShZhr9tbjpDVNmLMgQkFfWsnZhLey
testnet=1
server=1
```

Also I tried integrating with bitcoind using json-rpc client as well which resulted in the same error.

Really appreciate any help in resolving this error.  Thank you in advance. Let me know if you need any further details.

Regards, 
Manjunath

====== EDIT ======

When I inspect the request and response, its giving "Remote server closed the connection before sending response header" error as part of HTTP failure scenario. Following is the request data content :

URL : `http://192.168.2.111:18333/`

Request Data:

{
   "method": "getblockcount",
   "params": [],
   "id": "1"
}

Please help me in understanding where the mistake is.

================ EDIT =================

Added below entries to bitcoin.conf to allow connections from client. But still facing the same error:

```
rpcallowip=192.168.2.111
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
```

Regards, 
Manjunath

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After all tweaking, I am able to get it working properly. For the benefit of others, here is the Java Code for making JSON-RPC calls to bitcoind (Using Jersey Client):

bitcoin.conf entries :

```
rpcuser=bitcoinrpc
rpcpassword=5UKQTzWTf7EEJnkShZhr9tbjpDVNmLMgQkFfWsnZhLey    
testnet=1
server=1
#txindex=1
rpcallowip=192.168.2.*
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
rpcport=8999
#rpctimeout=60000
```

Make sure you change the port number and dont forget to provide rpcallowip entry pointing to respective IP address.

Client Code:

```
DefaultClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();

config.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING,
            Boolean.TRUE);
Client client = Client.create(config);
client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(username, password));
WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);
String input = "{\"id\":\"jsonrpc\",\"method\":\"listaccounts\",\"params\":[]}";
ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json").type("application/json")
           .post(ClientResponse.class, input);
```

Thats it. Your good to start with bitcoind integration.

Regards, 
Manjunath