# Cannot call Bitcoin RPC from Jersey HttpClient

Tags: java, jersey, bitcoin

im using dropwizard. From a resource i try to use bitcoin rpc via Jersey HttpClient.

using curl works like a charm:
$ curl --user user:password -X POST -d '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "getinfo", "params":
[] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://domain.name:18332/

But somehow using Jersey HTTP client from a resource doesnt work:

```
    //init in run methode
    final Client client = new JerseyClientBuilder(e).using(c.getJerseyClientConfiguration()).build(getName());
    HTTPBasicAuthFilter httpBasicAuth = new HTTPBasicAuthFilter("user", "password");
    client.addFilter(httpBasicAuth);

    //From the resource
    WebResource webRes = client.resource("http://domain.name:18332/");      
    webRes.header("content-type", "text/plain");

    RPC_REQUEST rpc = new RPC_REQUEST("1.0", "curltest", "getinfo", new ArrayList<String>());
    String response = webRes.post(String.class, JSONParserHelper.parseJSONToString(rpc));
```

JSONParserHelper.parseJSONToString(rpc) returns following string:

```
    {"jsonrpc":"1.0","id":"curltest","method":"getinfo","params":[]}
```

Following error is caused in row "webRes.post":

```
    ! com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: Client response status: 500
```

EDIT: Using a wrong pw causes a 401. I guess the connection should be correct and the issue is somewhere else.

EDIT: Used -d instead of --data-binary

EDIT: As soon as Im home Ill dump the whole request from jersey http client.

Thank you

Comment: Just found someone with a similar issue. Will check that out today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25726921/bitcoind-json-rpc-java-jersey-client-unexpected-end-of-file-from-server-erro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitcoin RPC does not support chunked encoding requests.
Since there was a bug in dropbox jersey libs till 0.8 you cannot disable it.

Since 0.8 you can disable it in the configuration file.
I had to migrate from 0.7 to 0.8 and add this in my configuration file.

httpClient:
  ...
  chunkedEncodingEnabled: false

By the way a good migration overview: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dropwizard-dev/VInOW_ebiAc